# Determining the relationship between Stories and Pages

Tags: adobe-indesign

A bit of background before I astart: I am by no means an InDesign expert, but I've been tasked with pulling some text information out of our company's InDesign files to do a bit of analytics.  Each InDesign file that I'm working with has multiple pages, and each of those pages use Stories from the Master page (Forgive me if I'm using the wrong terminology, I'm working on a limited understanding of the InDesign object model).  Using the default Export All Text script as a starting point, I was able to expand that functionality to dump out other useful information; such as the geometric bounds.   I've posted some of the code below:

```
myFileName = "StoryID" + myID + myExtension;
myFilePath = myFolder + "/" + myFileName;
myFile = new File(myFilePath);

myFile.encoding='text';
myFile.open('w');

containers = myStory.textContainers;

if (containers[0].overridden) {
    for (i = 0; i < myStory.words.length; i++) {
        myFile.write(myStory.words[i].contents);
        myFile.write(" ");
    }
    myFile.write("\n");
}
else {
    myFile.write(myStory.contents + '\n');
}

var geometry = containers[0].geometricBounds
myFile.write("++" + containers[0].parent.name + '\n');
myFile.write("$$" + geometry[0] + "\t" + geometry[1] + "\t" + geometry[2] + "\t" + geometry[3] + "\n");

pageitems = myStory.allPageItems;
for (j = 0; j < pageitems.length; j++){
    myFile.write("--" + pageitems[0]);
}
myFile.close();
```

The question I have is, how do I determine all the pages that a Story appears in?  For example, I lets say I have 4 pages: {Master, Region 1, Region 2, Region 3}.  Region 1 - 3 all inherit a Story block from Master.  When I run this script I only get one instance of the Story block, the instance belonging to Master.  However, I would be interested to know that the Story block in question belongs to all 4 pages.  I've tried accessing the allPageItems property but I keep getting 0 results.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm working on InDesign CS 6 if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're accessing `allPageItems` of the `Story` element, you're accessing all of the page items that are anchored within that story, which I don't think is what you want.

When you access the `allPageItems` property you get 0 results because your `Story` doesn't contain any `textFrames`. The `Story` element is contained by `textContainers` not `textFrames`. I know it's confusing!

If you want to determine whether a story is on a particular page, you can access the `textContainers`’ `parentPage` property.

A `Story` flows through multiple `textContainers`. For example:

```
                  link                         link
TextContainer      -->      TextContainer2      -->      TextContainer3
|_____________________________________________________________________|
                                   |
                                 Story
```

A `Story` can also contain `textFrames`, `rectangles`, `words`, etc. For example:

```
                                 Story
___________________________________|__________________________________
|                                                                     |
Word  -->  Word2  -->  TextFrame  -->   Word3  -->   Word4  -->   Word5
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Josh, that was really helpful!  Are you familiar with how overrides are represented in the object model?  For example if Story1 is overridden with new text, does that appear as a new TextContainer in the original Story, or a new Story object where the overridden property is true?

Comment: Mmmm, trying to understand what you're saying. If a page has a master sheet applied to it, then the items that were on the master sheet are applied to the page but you can't change them because they aren't overridden yet. If you want to override an item on that page, you need to call the `override` function on that item like this: `masterPageItem.override(pageItem)`.

Comment: You can probably think about it like the `pageItem` is still on the master sheet until you override it on the actual page... maybe, hopefully I'm not confusing myself.

Comment: Cool, that's what I understand of the Pages <--> Master Sheet relationship.  However, how would I go about detecting which pageItems were overrides of a MasterPageItem?  I guess there's always the overridden field.  I have a feeling that the task ahead of me may be a more difficult than I thought.  Thanks for the insight Josh